# Yii2 Migration to increase column length

Tags: mysql, yii2, schema

In Yii2 I wish to create a migration to change the character limit of a varchar column from 255 to 765.

Using `$this->alterColumn('my_table', 'text_column', 'string');`will make the column 255 as is. I'm thinking of using mysql to change the column to **TEXT** instead of **Varchar**, but is there a way to do this in Yii2?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Changing `varchar` length:

```
$this->alterColumn('my_table', 'text_column', $this->string(765));
```

Changing column type to `text`:

```
$this->alterColumn('my_table', 'text_column', $this->text());
```

You can find more examples in [Migrations documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-migrations).